# How to build a record of a many_to_many relation with a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, activerecord, nested

Say, I have two model in a `many to many` relationship (without additional attributes), so a simple `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

For the purpose, let's say I have a `user` model and a `course` model.And the corresponding join table `courses_users` has only the foreign keys `user_id` and `course_id` as attributes.

Now I'm listing *(say in the show page of the `user`)* all the `course` and according to if the current `user` has enrolled or not *(i.e. if a record exist in the join table)* I display a cross ✘ or a check ✔.
No problem thus far.

The problem is that I'm unable to make it editable in a form.

I mean **how** can I associate a **form checkbox** with the fact that **if it is checked I build** a relation, and **if not I delete it**?

Thank you very much.

---

Here is my simple models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

And here is my form attempt but I don't know at all what to do next.
I thought about checking for the foreign key of the course..

```
<%= form_with model: @user do |form| %>
  <%= @courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= form.fields_for :courses do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.check_box 'course_id', checked: (@user.courses.include? course.id) %>
      <%= ff.label 'course_id' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: see [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), best for nested forms. You can dynamically add and remove nested form elements.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look.. But I would want to know how to handle that with regular rails...

Comment: by looking at your problem I think you'll need JQuery/Javascript to achieve the required functionality... and the gem I referred will do exactly the same (will provide JQuery implementation for this)

Comment: I thought that this is not something related to the client side. I mean if I could built that form correctly with rails forms or if I can have the "data" built by some JS.. I'll just get some kind of structured params.. But I'll still need a way to understand that params and build according relationships in the controller.